# Firebase query not applying "where"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

Im trying to do a multiple filter system. So I need to be able to add a "where" depending the filters that I got.

When I try to add the "where" like this, the snapshot has the correct houses.

```
const houses = db
  .collection("Houses")
  .where("ventRent", "==", "Sell")
  .limit(paginaSize);

const snapshot = await houses.get();
```

But when I try to add the "where" like this, the snapshot has every house, as if it didn't do the "where".

```
const houses = db
  .collection("Houses")
  .limit(paginaSize);

if(filters) {
  if(filters.selectCR) {
    if(filters.selectCR === "Selling") {
      houses.where("ventRent", "==", "Sell");
    } else {
      houses.where('ventRent', '==', "Rent");
    }
  }
}

const snapshot = await houses.get();
```

I've tried changing to let, var and const and nothing. I've change the '' to "" or vice versa and nothing too.

I think Im doing it in the correct way, but I have no idea why is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `where` it returns a new query. So you have to assign the result of `houses.where(...)` to a variable, typically back to `houses.

So for example:

```
houses = houses.where("ventRent", "==", "Sell");
```

Then at the end when you call `houses.get()`, you're calling it on the completed query.